# Using Security Manager in JBoss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: security, jboss

I'm trying to get the `Security Manager` to work in JBoss 5.1.0 GA, which seems to be lacking the `JbossPublicKey.RSA`.

Hence I could not import the public key, I couldn't create a keystore to use it with the Security Manager. This gives me a lot of `no signer certificates` errors.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `JbossPublicKey.RSA` is basically the `cacerts` file that the used JRE point to. By default this file is `<JRE root>/lib/security/cacerts`. I guess you get the `no signer certificate` because you lack the proper certificate in this file.

You can call the file whatever you like, and place it wherever you want as long as you tell the JRE where to find it. IIRC it's called `TrustStore` in the JRE configuration.